# Firebase and android app, retrieve unreaded notifications

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the different tutorials for implementing management notification via Firebase to an android application. I send notifications via php with:
delay_while_idle: true and time_to_live: 0

It works well when the application and in the background or foreground.
When the application is killed, it works on my emulator (BlueStacks), but not on my "Elephon P3000".

The Android side code used is the one sited in various posts here (`FirebaseMessagingService`, `FirebaseInstanceIdService` etc ...)

Is there a way, when the application is launched, it retrieve the unread notifications?

Answer (score 0):

The way FCM works, the soonest the device goes online and successfully establishes a connection, the FCM server will send the messages as soon as possible.

There are, however, some parameters that you include in the payload that can cause some delays, such as the `delay_while_idle`. See the [Lifetime of a Message docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) for more details.